# Query parameter added to HTTP as javascript function

Tags: javascript, django, http

I see there're some periodical requests with script in the query parameter when I'm looking at my google analytics, something looks like this

```
/about?RaNDMPRMz='-function(){debugger}()-">\"><scrIpt>debugger</scrIpt><aUdio src=x oNerror=debugger><"-'-function(){debugger}()
```

It appears almost through out all available pages, like /home/, /events/..
What does this kind of query mean and should I worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone is apparently looking for vulnerabilities in your code that will allow him to inject javascript code into your site. Should you worry about it? Only if that someone will find something, but before that you should review your code to find and fix possible vulnerabilities.

Comment: I've no idea what to fix and how this injection will work. Is the way that google about XSS attack right direction?